# Facebook and Instagram images are broken in some browsers

Tags: browser, ssl, ssl-certificate, tls, windows-10-v1803

On my main computer (Windows 10, 1803, 17134.165) no images or videos on Facebook or Instagram are displayed when using most browsers.

All of the images and videos (from both sites) are being served from a CDN - `*.flhr2-2.fna.fbcdn.net`

If I try to open an image directly I get the following errors:

- Chrome (68.0.3440.84) & Opera (54.0.2952.64):

> **This site can’t provide a secure connection**
>
> **instagram.flhr2-2.fna.fbcdn.net** uses an unsupported protocol.
>
> **Unsupported protocol**
>
> The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.

- Edge (42.17134.1.0) & IE (11.165.17134.0):

> **Cannot securely connect to this page**
>
> This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website’s owner.

Chrome includes an error code - `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`

Both sites work fine on Firefox (61.0.1).

Both sites work fine on other computers on my network - Windows 10 and Linux Mint 19, using the same versions of the same browsers.

So, it would appear to be something SSL related, on my main PC.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Chrome, IE and Edge use the same stack for TLS processing, while Firefox uses its own.  Check Internet Explorer Settings' Advanced tab for SSL/TLS options. Compare them with the working other Windows 10 machines.

Comment: Identical on working and non-working PCs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can check :

- The correct date & time is set
- Enable all SSL/TLS Versions (a security risk).
  In Chrome this is in
  Settings > Advanced Settings > Open proxy settings > Advanced, 
  scroll down to the Security section and check all SSL and TLS versions,
  click Apply, relaunch Chrome.
- Clear all browsing data
- Clear the SSL State. In Chrome this done in
  Settings > Advanced Settings > Open proxy settings,
  in Internet Properties, Content tab, click on Clear SSL State.
- Disable the QUIC Protocol in `chrome://flags/#enable-quic`
- Check if your antivirus blocks insecure SSL/TLS protocols
- Delete your cache and cookies ([Chrome link](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?hl=en)).
- In Chrome use incognito mode. If this helps then temporarily disable your extensions to identify which one is causing the problem, in
  `chrome://extensions`.
- Reset your browser settings.

Comment: So it looks like it was my AntiVirus - BitDefender has an option for Scan SSL. I switched it off and all is working again